# Strange black dim under UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationbar, autolayout

Recently I've faced a strange thing in my app. I don't know if this is a bug but it's annoying.

I've a view hierarchy like on the screenshot below:

[image: view hierarchy]

... and when I move my app to the background (tapping on the home button) there appears a black dim under `UINavigationBar`. Of course it stays in the task-switching mode (screenshot below). I don't know what caused this bug and of course I don't know how to get rid of this.

[image]

Comment: I've experienced this issue in one of my apps too. I cannot tell you how I resolved it but I *think* it had something to do with the view hierarchy. I'm not having access to that project right now but I'll take a look at it later today! I hope I can find it again, I remember how annoying that was! But it was not a bug in the framework.

Comment: @HAS it would be great if you could take a look in your code! IMHO, I might have made a little mess and this is why I'm facing this but I have no idea where is this mistake.

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to fix this problem directly but as I said it is a problem with hierarchy and I'll try to explain it just the way I understand it so if I'm wrong, don't hasitate to correct me!

`UIView` called Groups is filling only the space under the `UINavigationBar`. In that case there is nothing under the bar. So why is it displaying this dim? I guess because of the native blur effect under `UINavigationBar`.

So how did I manage to deal with this without changing the view hierarchy? I've changed the size of `UIView` to cover whole window and because `UIView` has some backround set the dim effect disappeared. This operation is easy to achieve. Just by selecting Extended edges **Under Top Bars** option in Attributes Inspector of View Controller

[image: noname]

Comment: + 1 for solving the issue, nevertheless I'm trying to figure out how I solved the problem ;)

Comment: I just had the issue. and I solved it by setting navigationBar.translucent = NO; for the navigationController which holds the rootViewController. in your case GroupsViewController's navigation bas needs be translucent to NO. ;)